# TextRenderer.DrawText() does not work on my Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to render text into GDI(not GDI+) and save as image in C#.NET web application not windows application, SO for that I have chosen `TextRenderer.DrawText()`, to render the text into GDI, But I am getting an red lined highlight below the `TextRenderer` with message  if mouse over **"The name 'TextRenderer' does not exist in the current context"** . here my code is:

```
Bitmap Bit = new Bitmap(1000,500);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bit);
g.Clear(Color.Red);
TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, myText, new Font("Ariel", 50, FontStyle.Regular), new Point(20, 20), Color.Black, Color.Gold);
Bit.Save(pathToSaveImg + "image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
Bit.Dispose();
```

So PLEASE help if any Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use [`TextRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx) you need to include the line

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

on top of your code file and reference the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in your project.